# how to build Xamarin Visual Studio Project without Login Xamarin Account

Tags: xamarin

I have Xamarin.Android8.0.2.1 installed version on visual studio 2015 when i try to build Xamarin Application it ask me to login to xamarin account 
Must I login to build and run Xamarin application?

Comment: plz reply if you found solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem has been solved,the problem was in the license file, i reinstall the Xamarin, the login window still appears but the build operation continues without problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Xamarin Account to develop and build Xamarin Apps. I have work with both (VS 2015 and VS 2017) without it.

[image: Not logged Xamarin account]

I hope this can help you.

Comment: just i build the application the login windows appears,when i close it the output windows show "Build has been canceled" i have installed visual studio 2015 Enterprise Edition with Xamarin.Android 8.0.2.1

Comment: Maybe is due to VS15 EE, in VS17 Xamarin has changed a lot.